# How to animate box-shadow inside division in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on Carousel.It is inside the division in that i need to set shadow inside the division and i want to animate the shadow inside the division as i want 
but boxShadow animation is working when i applied to the outside of the division 
but when i applied the same to the inside shadow it is not working.

```
$("#"+index).animate({ boxShadow : "200px 0px 80px 30px #ffffff"
},1000);
```

the above code is working

but

```
$("#"+index).animate({ boxShadow : "inset 200px 0px 80px 30px #ffffff"
    },1000);
```

this is not working

i don't know what's happening

Comment: I'd suggest using css animations. Not jquery. So add/remove a class when you want to animate

Comment: @Venkat Lokeswar what version of jQuery library you are using.

Comment: i think what you said is correct let me try using it by the way my current version is  1.11.3 @Unamata Sanatarai

Answer (score 0):

why not use css animation dude?

its simple just need add

```
transtion: box-shadow 1s ease-in;
```

or if you want to run animation continous just use keyframe
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Comment: ya i know that one but i need it in jQuery